# Group By does not take into account the changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

first off, I apologize if this was asked before.

I got a query which returns the name of the country versus the bookings made in the last year.

however, the output requirement is to have the 4 countries within the UK to be all classed as "UK".

my query is:

```
select distinct

    [Exiting Country] = case
        when co.COUNTRY_NM in ('ENGLAND', 'N. IRELAND', 'SCOTLAND', 'WALES', 'UNITED KINGDOM')
            then 'UK'
        else co.COUNTRY_NM
    end
    ,count(bk.booking_id) as [Number of Bookings]

from dbo.BOOKINGS as bk
left join dbo.COUNTRY as co
    on bk.COUNTRY_ID = co.COUNTRY_ID

group by co.COUNTRY_NM

order by [Exiting Country] asc
```

however the result will be as:

[image]

how can i have it to group it by the modified country name instead? any simple way to do it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the `case` expression in the `group by`:

```
select (case when co.COUNTRY_NM in ('ENGLAND', 'N. IRELAND', 'SCOTLAND', 'WALES', 'UNITED KINGDOM')
            then 'UK'
            else co.COUNTRY_NM
        end) as country,
       count(bk.booking_id) as num_bookings
from dbo.COUNTRY co left join
     dbo.BOOKINGS bk
     on bk.COUNTRY_ID = co.COUNTRY_ID
group by (case when co.COUNTRY_NM in ('ENGLAND', 'N. IRELAND', 'SCOTLAND', 'WALES', 'UNITED KINGDOM')
               then 'UK'
               else co.COUNTRY_NM
          end)
order by country asc;
```

Note the other changes to the query:

- The column names are simplified.  Try to avoid situations where you need to escape the name.
- The `left join` is inverted.  Presumably, you want to keep all countries, even when there are no matches.

Some databases allow you to use the column alias in the `group by` as well as the `order by`; alas, SQL Server is not one of those.

EDIT:

You can phrase this as:

```
select v.country,
       count(bk.booking_id) as num_bookings
from dbo.COUNTRY co left join
     dbo.BOOKINGS bk
     on bk.COUNTRY_ID = co.COUNTRY_ID cross apply
     (values (case when co.COUNTRY_NM in ('ENGLAND', 'N. IRELAND', 'SCOTLAND', 'WALES', 'UNITED KINGDOM')
                   then 'UK'
                   else co.COUNTRY_NM
               end)
     ) v(country)
group by v.country
order by v.country asc;
```

Comment: many thanks Gordon :) yeh it is weird that I could order by the new column, but not group by it :/

Comment: @P.MAJ To avoid repeating yourself, you can put the `case` calculation into a `CROSS APPLY` so that you can access that new column both in the group by and the select

Comment: @Charlieface, can you kindly give me an example of the script with CROSS APPLY please?

Comment: Overkill for this example as the CASE WHEN is really quite simple, but good to know for those situations where you have a huge, complex CASE WHEN statement you'd like to avoid duplicating in the GROUP BY.

Comment: @P.MAJ I see Gordon's done a great job with `CROSS APPLY`, as you can see, it adds a column to the query which you can then reference elsewhere.